# Most efficient way to load form fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm designing a form whereby a user can select from a selectbox, and based on their selection, it will dynamically load fields based on their selection. For example they can choose between two choices:

```
Red Sedan
Blue Truck
```

Once they have chosen one, fields unique to their choice will be loaded below:

```
Do you want the sedan's electric windows
Do you want the sedan's winter tires
```

etc.

The problem is, I will likely have many (~20) selections, each requiring a very different set of form fields of up to 60 fields each (20x60 = 1200 total form fields);

So the most brute force way would be to made 60 hidden divs and hide/show them accordingly, or to hard code my forms into javascript and append as the user selects a choice, but I feel like this is very inefficient.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Is it possible to store these forms in another place (i.e. another library) and access them as I need them?

I'm not entirely familiar with AJAX and what it is, but would it allow me to access the DB using php dynamically and load the fields that way? For example if I stored an array corresponding to each form in a MySQL DB, then loaded them each with JS as necessary.

Thank you for any help! Sorry if my question is vague.

Comment: are you saying that you have 1200 UNIQUE form elements?

Comment: Yes exactly, basically imagine you are a mechanic and there are a total of 20 unique problems someone might have with a car. In order to fix each one you may need to carry out up to 60 subtasks. Each field corresponds to a 'sub-task'. It's hard to explain but yes, you can think of it as 60x20 unique elements. Can this be done with AJAX? (See my edit above)

Comment: now I'm more confused :) - is it a static list of 1200 UNIQUE elements, or a variable number of potential elements, as decided by the mechanic (or whomever)? I ask because if it's the brakes for example, do you want 20 different elements that ask about fixing the brakes? that seems unnecessary... or maybe I still don't completely understand... and yes, you could dynamically load the info via ajax through a database call

Comment: Haha okay, here is what I'm doing without any more bad analogies.
I work in a biochemistry lab, and I'm making a database system where everyone can input their data. When you do something in the lab i.e. extract DNA, you must follow a certain protocol. Each protocol is standard but parameters may be changed (used 50mL ethanol instead of 30mL <-- things that should be documented). When a user wants to add an entry to the database, they would pick DNA isolation, then fields like "volume of ethanol used" would appear. Is that more clear? There are just so many protocols and parameters.

Comment: But coming back to your last sentence, could I do the following:

1. make a table in mySQL called "protocols"
2. each entry is a different lab protocol (i.e. DNA isolation).
3. each entry has an array stored in that when echoed will display an HTML form specific to that protocol
4. The form can be filled out and submitted into a different table (data entry table)

Comment: in theory, yes that can be done. You would need to create your own parser and array structure when displaying the form element, to know what type of element it is, and what options it has, default value, etc. BTW, what happened to the cars? :)

Comment: Haha okay awesome, Looks like I will be reading and watching lots of tutorials on AJAX in my near future. I just learned jQuery but I have a good amount of experience with HTML/CSS/PHP so hopefully I can do this on my own

Comment: there's lots of tutorials out there so you should be good - you should include what you are going to do in an answer, and then mark it accepted as soon as the system will let you - keeps it out of the unanswered questions list.